# Up to 2 trailing digits after decimal

Tags: jquery, checkbox

Following is the jQuery code

```
    $('#Cancelation').change(function(){        
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
            total = parseFloat($('#TotalAmount').val()) + parseFloat($('#Cancelation').val());                      
        } else {
        total = parseFloat($('#TotalAmount').val()) - parseFloat($('#Cancelation').val());
        }
        $('#TotalAmount').val(total);
        $('#TotalPrice').html(total);
    });
```

If the `#TotalAmount` value is 10.49 which shows correctly on page load and problem is that if checkbox checked or unchecked, value of checkbox which is 2.00 added or subtract from `#TotalAmount` and `#TotalPrice` but the output shows like `12.48999998` on add 0r `10.48999998` on subtract.

I tried `.toFixed(2);` but the result is same, any other way to fix the issue?

Edited: HTML Code

```
<label for="Cancelation"><input type="checkbox" name="Cancelation" id="Cancelation" value="2.00"> Cancellation Protection: 2.00</label>
<input type="text" name="TotalAmount" id="TotalAmount" value="10.49" />
Total Amount: <span id="TotalPrice">10.49</span>
```

Comment: can you post your html

Comment: html code added in question.

Comment: your code seems to work http://jsfiddle.net/2c9uy9cw/

Comment: @depperm agree with you it worked I used same code same way on another site and there its working but the page I'm currently working on its not working as it should be, so any idea or any solution coz i don't see a way to debug a correctly working code

Comment: do you have any other js that affects Cancelation, TotalAmount, or TotalPrice?

Comment: yes and as you mentioned i deleted all the other js and just keep the code in question just to be sure and checked, the result is same, no change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After little bit research and checking answers at following link

[Round to at most 2 decimal places in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832914/round-to-at-most-2-decimal-places-in-javascript)

Sorted the problem with adding java, Thanks to **mac** who suggested `Math.round`.

```
<script>
    var round = Math.round;
    Math.round = function (value, decimals) {
      decimals = decimals || 0;
      return Number(round(value + 'e' + decimals) + 'e-' + decimals);
    }

    $('#Cancelation').change(function(){        
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
            total = parseFloat($('#TotalAmount').val()) + parseFloat($('#Cancelation').val());                      
        } else {
            total = parseFloat($('#TotalAmount').val()) - parseFloat($('#Cancelation').val());
        }
            $("#TotalAmount").val(Math.round(total, 2));
            $("#TotalPrice").html(Math.round(total, 2));
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Math.round(number * 100) / 100` to round to two decimal places.